# logging into a website and downloading a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to log into a website and download a file.  I'm using selenium and the chromedriver. Would like to know if there is a better way.  It currently opens up a chrome browser window and sends the info.  I don't want to see the browser window opened up and the data being sent.  Just want to send it and return the data into a variable.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def site_login(URL,ID_username,ID_password,ID_submit,name,pas):
  driver.get(URL)
  driver.find_element_by_id(ID_username).send_keys(name)
  driver.find_element_by_id(ID_password).send_keys(pas)
  driver.find_element_by_id(ID_submit).click()


URL = "www.mywebsite.com/login"
ID_username = "name"
ID_password = "password"
ID_submit = "submit"

name = "myemail@mail.com"
pas = "mypassword"

resp=site_login(URL,ID_username,ID_password,ID_submit,name,pas)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run chrome in headless mode. In which case, the chrome UI won't show up and still performing the task you were doing. Some article I found on this https://intoli.com/blog/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome/. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.  This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this two lines

```
chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
```

This should make chrome run in the background.

Comment: Gives me an error on the '**' at the end.  Is this a typo?

Answer (score 0):

First option: If you are able to change the driver, you can use phantom-js as driver. That was a headless browser and you can use it with selenium.

Second option: If the site are not dynamic (easily called it SPA) or you are able to trace packet (which can be done in chrome dev tools), you can directly use request with the help of beautifulsoup if you need to get some data on the page.